# Oracle ERROR : INVALID SQL STATEMENT ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have maked an stored procedure but I cannot execute the stored procedure I dont know what the problem is.

Source code:

```
Create or replace procedure land_naam(klantnummer_input in VARCHAR2
, verzendland_output out VARCHAR2)

AS 

BEGIN

SELECT land into verzendland_output from klanten 

WHERE klantnummer = klantnummer_input;

END land_naam;
```

First I create the procedure without any error.

Then if I want to execute it I run the code

```
Execute land_naam;
```

after that I get the error :

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

What can i do to solve this problem?
[The procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmEtg.png)
[The error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta4R5.png)

Comment: from what I can tell, you're specifying `klantnummer_input` as an input parameter.  You have to pass a value for it `Execute land_naam(some_input_value)`

Comment: What do you think `(klantnummer_input in VARCHAR2
, verzendland_output out VARCHAR2)` mean?

Comment: Still getting the same error If I pass value for it I tryed execute land_naam('S');

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to something like this:

```
Create or replace procedure land_naam(klantnummer_input in VARCHAR2)
AS 
verzendland_output VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
SELECT land into verzendland_output from klanten 
WHERE klantnummer = klantnummer_input;
END land_naam;
```

When executing the procedure, since you have an input parameter, provide one.

```
e.g. EXECUTE land_naam('S');
```

Answer (score 0):

As your procedure is specifying both an input and an output parameter, you'll have to specify those when calling your procedure:

To declare a variable in SQLPlus that will hold the output, simple use

```
SQL> var out varchar2(100)
```

Then call the stored procedure with an input and output parameter (otherwise you're not specifying the correct number of parameters)

```
SQL> exec land_naam('yourinput', :out)
```

Finally, print out the contents of your output variable

```
SQL> print out
```

Comment: I dont know what you exactly mean